# How to get the last line of a Sharepoint List with Powershell PnP?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I have created a SharePoint-environment and I use powershell to maintain my SharePoint. I use the Powershell module "Patterns and Practices PowerShell for SharePoint Online". I try to create a code to get the last line of a SharePoint list. Does someone know how to do that?

I don't get further than this:

```
$List = Get-PnPList -Identify "NieuweLijst"
```

Who can help me?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86509/discussion-on-question-by-peter-kiers-how-to-get-the-last-line-of-a-sharepoint-l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the last item of the list:

```
 Get-PnPListItem -List "NieuweLijst" | select -Last 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86510/discussion-on-answer-by-r-sperre-how-to-get-the-last-line-of-a-sharepoint-list).